# Creating a Queue in C++

Tags: c++, queue

I'm assigned to create a queue of locations with an x and y coordinate. I properly read in a file to a vector of vectors called spaceStation which has the corresponding columns and rows of locations of certain characters that are significant.  I'm supposed to create a queue that enqueues locations which i would interpret as a queue that contains an x, and a y coordinate of some character.

I believe choosing a 2d vector would be good to queue so I was curious about the syntax.
Would it be something like the following

```
queue<int,vector< vector<int> > > order;
```

If i were to name it order.

Comment: No, it would not. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: `std::vector` is a data type for representing variable-length lists, not for coordinate pairs, which are called 'vector' in geometry.  To store a coordinate pair, try `std::pair<int,int>` or `std::array<int,2>`.  Use a typedef to make it easier to replace with a type that does arithmetic, if you need that in the future.

Comment: I guess you need `queue<pair<int,int>>`

Comment: How are you going to use the locations? It really depends on what you are going to do with the coordinates.

Comment: For example, the first location to be queued is a starting location which i kept track of the coordinates from the inital read in to a 2d vector called spaceStation.  From there, I need to look north,east,west,south in that vector to check specific characters. If the character is a possible path, I need to queue that location.

Comment: For legibility in this and future problems, I suggest you start by defining your coordinate structure: `typedef pair<int, int> point_t`. Then use the `point_t` type in the container structure, be it a `vector` a `queue`, etc.

Comment: okay that makes sense. My other question would be is when loading this point_t for instance. I would call it's member functions and load the appropiate values. Then call the queues member function and push that point_t i created?

Comment: @JoshHamet That sounds reasonable (kind of). I do think you'd be better off trying these things out rather than asking questions about them. Try things first, ask all the questions you like afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

`std::queue` is not a container but a container adapter, where the second template parameter indicates the internal container that is adapted. For your program, you can just use the following:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> Coordinate;
typedef queue<Coordinate> CoordinateQueue;
```